# How can I use the TestScheduler with promises and delays?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, jasmine, rxjs

I'm trying to get Jasmine, promises and Rx.TestScheduler to play nicely together, but I've run into an obstacle I can't seem to work around.

What I'm trying to achieve is testing a delayed promise using RxJs and Jasmine.

I have a created a minimal reproduction of the problem in this JsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/t9gsymu2/2/

This is the full javascript code of that fiddle:

```
'use strict';

// fail if a test takes longer than 1 second
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 1000;

describe('TestScheduler', function () {
    it('should work when combining the testscheduler and delay', function (done) {
        var scheduler = new Rx.TestScheduler();
        var people = Rx.Observable.just({
            name: 'Jeff'
        });
        var peopleWithTheirAge = people.flatMap(function (person) {
            return Rx.Observable.just({
                name: 'Jeff',
                age: 25
            });
        });
        var delayedPeopleWithTheirAge = peopleWithTheirAge.delay(2000, scheduler);
        delayedPeopleWithTheirAge.subscribe(function (person) {
            expect(person).toEqual({
                name: 'Jeff',
                age: 25
            });
            done();
        });
        scheduler.start();
    });

    it('should work when combining the testscheduler, delay AND a promise', function (done) {
        var scheduler = new Rx.TestScheduler();
        var people = Rx.Observable.just({
            name: 'Jeff'
        });
        var peopleWithTheirAge = people.flatMap(function (person) {
            return Promise.resolve({
                name: 'Jeff',
                age: 25
            });
        });
        var delayedPeopleWithTheirAge = peopleWithTheirAge.delay(2000, scheduler);
        delayedPeopleWithTheirAge.subscribe(function (person) {
            expect(person).toEqual({
                name: 'Jeff',
                age: 25
            });
            done();
        });
        scheduler.start();
    });
});
```

Both tests are identical to a T, the only difference being that the first test uses `Rx.Observable.just` and the second test uses `Promise.resolve`.
(I could use `Rx.Observable.fromPromise` to make sure an Observable is actually created, but 1. I've tried that and 2. The documentation at https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/promises.md explicitly states that flatMap supports Promise objects)

The first test succeeds instantly. The Observable gets delayed by 2 seconds using the Rx.TestScheduler, which can simulate time. The `scheduler.start()` method executes any scheduled tasks immediately instead of waiting 2 seconds. Jasmine supports asynchronous tests using a "done" parameter in your test, which is really just a function that you need to call whenever you consider the test finished.

However, the second test fails. I'm assuming this has something to do with Promises being asynchronous, which causes the TestScheduler to not pick up on anything that happens in those callbacks.

Any help on this matter would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on fire lately, that's the second time I've found the answer shortly after posting my question on SO.

Anyway, the solution is to use the MockPromise built in to the RxJs library.

So instead of using `Promise.resolve(true)`, use `scheduler.createResolvedPromise(100, true)` instead.

Here is the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t9gsymu2/4/

And the full code:

```
'use strict';

// fail if a test takes longer than 1 second
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 1000;

describe('TestScheduler', function () {
    it('should work when combining the testscheduler and delay', function (done) {
        var scheduler = new Rx.TestScheduler();
        var people = Rx.Observable.just({
            name: 'Jeff'
        });
        var peopleWithTheirAge = people.flatMap(function (person) {
            return Rx.Observable.just({
                name: 'Jeff',
                age: 25
            });
        });
        var delayedPeopleWithTheirAge = peopleWithTheirAge.delay(2000, scheduler);
        delayedPeopleWithTheirAge.subscribe(function (person) {
            expect(person).toEqual({
                name: 'Jeff',
                age: 25
            });
            done();
        });
        scheduler.start();
    });

    it('should work when combining the testscheduler, delay AND a promise', function (done) {
        var scheduler = new Rx.TestScheduler();
        var people = Rx.Observable.just({
            name: 'Jeff'
        });
        var peopleWithTheirAge = people.flatMap(function (person) {
            return scheduler.createResolvedPromise(100, {
                name: 'Jeff',
                age: 25
            });
        });
        var delayedPeopleWithTheirAge = peopleWithTheirAge.delay(2000, scheduler);
        delayedPeopleWithTheirAge.subscribe(function (person) {
            expect(person).toEqual({
                name: 'Jeff',
                age: 25
            });
            done();
        });
        scheduler.start();
    });
});
```

Comment: That is correct. One aside, you don't actually need `done` if you will be using a `TestScheduler`. After `start` returns all the values have been processed. Additionally, in general it is easier to use a `MockObserver` rather than explicitly doing a comparison in the subscribe block.

Comment: Thanks again for the additional info! I'm learning a lot from you. Are you a contributor to RxJs?

Comment: No problem! And yes I am one of the contributors.

Comment: Sadly this is not possible anymore: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2633